# Probability distribution help

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm trying to understand what kind of probability distribution I need to use in order to calculate a very simple example using a deck of cards.

Assume that there is a standard deck of cards (52 cards):

Let X be the number of non-hearts until I get 13 hearts (without replacement). What would be the distribution I need to use?

My guess is using Geometric distribution: $$X=Geometric (1/4)$$

Or would I need to use a Binomial distribution? $$X=Binomial(13, 1/4)$$

Can anyone please help me with what distribution I need to use? with parameters?

Comment: negative binomial

Comment: What are you doing? Taking cards and replace them into the deck if it is not a heart, or no replacing?

Comment: For this example, without replacement

Comment: @JKSA: you don't mention anywhere it's sampling without replacement

Comment: My apologise. Sorry

Comment: @JKSA Accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the cards in a row. If we only discern hearts and non-hearts
then there are $\binom{52}{13}$ arrangements. Now fix $n\in\left\{ 13,\dots,52\right\} $
and notice that there are $\binom{n-1}{12}$ arrangements such that
the last heart is placed on spot $n$. So denoting $N$ as the spot
of the last heart we come to: $$P\left(N=n\right)=\binom{n-1}{12}\binom{52}{13}^{-1}$$
Now realize that $X=N-13$ so that $$P\left(X=k\right)=P\left(N=k+13\right)=\binom{k+12}{12}\binom{52}{13}^{-1}$$
This for $k=0,1,\dots,39$.

Unfortunately I don't know a name for this distribution.

---

Equality $\sum_{n=13}^{52}P\left(N=n\right)=1$ leads to the observation
that $\sum_{n=12}^{51}\binom{n}{12}=\binom{52}{13}$. More generally
it can be shown (e.g. by induction) that $$\sum_{k=r}^{n}\binom{k}{r}=\binom{n+1}{r+1}$$
So a more general setting here would lead to a combinatorial proof of this
equality.